# Apache refuses to acknowledge my Sites folder

Tags: apache-2.2, mac, virtualhost, localhost, httpd.conf

I'm running Apache on a Mac, and all of the sudden `http://localhost` results in Apache's HTDOCS folder, while for some time now it correctly referred to my Sites folder.

Running `apachectl -D DUMP_HOSTS` yields:

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Some HTTPD.CONF settings:

```
Listen 80

DocumentRoot "/Users/[username]/Sites"

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/[username]/Sites"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

HELP.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. Do you maybe have two instances of httpd running? Try shutting down all instances (check with ps or similar they are all gone), then restart, then check again.

Is it possible an upgrade replaced your httpd with a new version that reads a different httpd.conf?

Comment: Good lead! Can you please direct me to the command you suggested?

Comment: *ps -lax* should do it. As for restarting apache on Mac OS, just check your documentation.

Comment: "/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND" is showed 4 times. Is that it?

Comment: Also "opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start" -- 6 times.